# Where does iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus simulators store its data?

Tags: ios, ios6, swift, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have a SQLite database file that using to store app data, and I could do with taking a look inside it to debug a problem I'm having but where does the iPhone6 & iPhone6 Plus Simulator store its data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the path of iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus simulator

/Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7C232505-04B5-4224-9377-94E37D26E6EC/data/Containers/Data/Application

Inside Devices folder you have see the different folder.Each folder contains a device.plist file.
In that plist file you can see the device type in the following way:

com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6